# Changing State In React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

**Background**

I am having a problem in my react app I am writing. I have been trying to remove a row from a table but I keep getting

> setState is undefined

So basically this is how I have this setup.

This function will remove the row from the table. 
   I have not tested this because I keep getting the

> error `setState` of undefined

.

```
function removeRow(id) {
  this.setState(state => {
     state.tableData.splice(id, 1);
     return {tableData: state.tableData};
   });
}
```

**Question**

How do I correctly remove the `tr` from the `table` when the `onClick method` fires of so that the `state` will change and `render` the `table` again without the `tr` that was removed?

**Examples**

This is the `onClick` method which is calling the `removeRow()`.

```
<td><a href="#" onClick={() => { removeRow(tableData[key].id) }}>Delete</a></td>
```

This is what it all looks like together,

```
var requests =  [   
        {"id":1, "title":"Request from Nancy","updated_at":"2015-08-15 12:27:01 -0600","created_at":"2015-08-12 08:27:01 -0600","status":"Denied"}
    ]

class TableDisplay extends React.Component {
constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      tableData: requests
    }
  }

  render() {
    const {tableData} = this.props;

    return (
      <div className="table-wrapper">
        <div><table className="table">
            <tr className="separate"><td>Title</td><td>Status</td>           
               <td>Created</td><td>Updated</td><td>Delete</td></tr>
     {Object.keys(tableData).map(function(key) {       

     function removeRow(id) {
         this.setState(state => {
            state.tableData.splice(id, 1);
            return {tableData: state.tableData};
        });
     }

        return // removed extra code to make it easy to read.
        <td><a href="#" onClick={() => { removeRow(tableData[key].id) }}>Delete</a></td>
        </tr>;

        })}
           </table>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

I also tried to move the `removeRow()` directly under the `constructor` and above the `render()` but when I do that then removeRow() throws an error when the onClick fires,

> removeRow is not defined.

```
class TableDisplay extends React.Component {
constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      tableData: requests
    }
  }

// I have to remove "function" from the declaration or the app wont render from parse error.

   removeRow(id) {
         this.setState(state => {
            state.tableData.splice(id, 1);
            return {tableData: state.tableData};
        });
     }

  render() {
    const {tableData} = this.props;

    return (
      <div className="table-wrapper">
        <div><table className="table">
            <tr className="separate"><td>Title</td><td>Status</td>           
               <td>Created</td><td>Updated</td><td>Delete</td></tr>
     {Object.keys(tableData).map(function(key) {       

        return // removed extra code to make it easy to read.
        <td><a href="#" onClick={() => { removeRow(tableData[key].id) }}>Delete</a></td>
        </tr>;

        })}
           </table>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a few issues with your component, namely the fact that you don't bind the context in the remove function (hence `setState` is undefined). Try something like this:

```js
const TableRow = (props) => (
   <tr>
      <td>{props.title}</td>
      <td>{props.status}</td>
      <td>{props.updated_at}</td>
      <td>{props.created_at}</td>
      <td><a href="#" onClick={() => props.remove(props.index)}>Delete</a></td>
   </tr>
)

class TableDisplay extends React.Component {

   constructor() {
      super();
      this.state = {
         tableData: [{
            "id":1,
            "title":"Request from Nancy",
            "updated_at":"2015-08-15 12:27:01 -0600",
            "created_at":"2015-08-12 08:27:01 -0600",
            "status":"Denied"
         }]
      };
   }

   remove(index) {
      this.setState({
         tableData: this.state.tableData.filter((row, i) => i !== index)
      });
   }

   render() {
      return (
         <div className="table-wrapper">
            <div>
               <table className="table">
                  <tbody>
                     {
                        this.state.tableData.map((row, i) => {
                           return (
                              <TableRow
                                 title={row.title}
                                 id={row.id}
                                 updated_at={row.updated_at}
                                 created_at={row.created_at}
                                 status={row.status}
                                 remove={this.remove.bind(this)}
                                 index={i}
                                 key={i} />
                           );
                        })
                     }
                  </tbody>
               </table>
            </div>
         </div>
      );
   }
}

ReactDOM.render((
   <TableDisplay />
), document.getElementById("app"));
```

Comment: Hey Max, I appreciate your help. Here is the jsfiddle I am working from maybe if you see the whole picture you might be able to tell me what my problem is better. https://jsfiddle.net/wuno/0wbof2pf/27/ I am trying to accomplish two things. 1. remove a row when delete is clicked. 2. When any value in the Status column is clicked allow the value to be changed to any of the respective values Approved,  Pending or Denied. But I have not been able to figure out how to change the data with React. I have accomplished this by directly changing the DOM though. But I know that is bad. I want to learn

Comment: Also I have been trying to do this with ES6 features. But I am wondering now if that is why I am having so many problems.

Comment: Hi @wuno I would recommend getting a bit more familiar with React and how elements are rendered. React is declarative, so as you mentioned, it's better to avoid direct DOM manipulation. Also, you should be consistent with your data. An array of objects would probably make more sense. Here is an update to your fiddle; unfortunately I didn't get a chance to implement your second condition, and I removed the styling for now -- https://jsfiddle.net/msindwan/0wbof2pf/28/

Comment: Thanks max. Ya I agree completely. I'll study what you did to see if I can figure out why my app would not work right.

Comment: Np! Let me know if you need more help

Answer (score 2):

The context of this is lost.

You can bind function to `this`.

```
class TableDisplay extends React.Component {
constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      tableData: requests
    }
  //ADD THIS LINE
  this.removeRow = this.removeRow.bind(this);
  }

// I have to remove "function" from the declaration or the app wont render from parse error.

   removeRow(id) {
         this.setState(state => {
            state.tableData.splice(id, 1);
            return {tableData: state.tableData};
        });
     }
 ......

<a href="#" onClick={() => { this.removeRow(tableData[key].id) }}
```

Or alternatively if you are using `ES6 Stage 2 preset`, you can use arrow functions

```
class TableDisplay extends React.Component {
constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      tableData: requests
    }
  }

// I have to remove "function" from the declaration or the app wont render from parse error.

   removeRow = (id) => {
         this.setState(state => {
            state.tableData.splice(id, 1);
            return {tableData: state.tableData};
        });
     }
 ......
```

Comment: When I do it the first way you show me I get this, Inline JSX script:158 Uncaught ReferenceError: removeRow is not defined
    at onClick (<anonymous>:158:101) and when I do it the second way you show me I get this, Uncaught Error: Parse Error: Line 80: Unexpected token =
removeRow = (id) => { I have tried all of the thing you are showing me and saw them in examples online as well as the docs. But for whatever reason it wont work. When I leave the function declaration inside the render function I can call the function and remove the row from the DOM directly but obviously I want react to

Comment: Please note that your alternative example isn't actually ES6. It relies on the [ES Class Fields & Static Properties Proposal](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-class-public-fields), which is still at stage-2 of the standardization property.

Comment: @wuno check now, i've updated how you are triggering the function

Comment: I am not seeing what you did differently? Cause this is still giving me setState of undefined.

Comment: @wuno two things 1) bind the function in constructor 2) call the function in render as this.removeRow.  Check if this 2 changes are reflected

Comment: Nope I still get errors. Would you like to see the jsfiddle? https://jsfiddle.net/wuno/0wbof2pf/27/

Comment: i don't see any binding in the fiddle as mentioned to do

Answer (score 1):

When you call `removeRow` in the second solution, you need to call it like `this.removeRow` since it is outside the render function. Also you need to bind it so that you can access `setState`. For this purpose you can use the arrow function

```
class TableDisplay extends React.Component {
constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      tableData: requests
    }
  }

// I have to remove "function" from the declaration or the app wont render from parse error.

   removeRow = (id) => {
         this.setState(state => {
            state.tableData.splice(id, 1);
            return {tableData: state.tableData};
        });
     }

  render() {
    const {tableData} = this.props;

    return (
      <div className="table-wrapper">
        <div><table className="table">
            <tr className="separate"><td>Title</td><td>Status</td>           
               <td>Created</td><td>Updated</td><td>Delete</td></tr>
     {Object.keys(tableData).map(function(key) {       

        return // removed extra code to make it easy to read.
        <td><a href="#" onClick={() => { this.removeRow(tableData[key].id) }}>Delete</a></td>
        </tr>;

        }.bind(this))}
           </table>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: When I use the arrow function and move the function below the constructor I get - Uncaught Error: Parse Error: Line 71: Unexpected token =

removeRow = (id) => { I have tried this example as well which I saw online but kept getting this error.

Comment: one morething you mus bind the map function so that removeRow is available with `this`. Try the update. Also make sure you are using ES6

Comment: I am doing this in a jsfiddle. I am creating all my components the es6 way but I have had this problem for 3 days now that every example of how to change state throws errors for me. You can see what I mean here https://jsfiddle.net/wuno/0wbof2pf/27/

Answer (score 1):

```
**Put removeRow method above render() and give current scope reference as var that = this; **


     class TableDisplay extends React.Component {
      constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      selectValue: 'all',
      tableData: requests
    }
    }

    removeRow() {
             this.setState(state => {
             state.tableData.splice(id, 1);
             return {tableData: state.tableData};
        });
     }

    render() {
    const {selectValue} = this.props;
    const {tableData} = this.props;
    var that = this;
     return (
      <div className="table-wrapper">
        <div><table className="table">
              <tr className="seperate"><td>Title</td><td>Status</td><td>Created</td><td>Updated</td><td>Delete</td></tr>
            {Object.keys(tableData).map(function(key) {  
        let styling = "bg-plain";
                let hidden = "hidden";
        let tds = document.querySelectorAll(".table td");
        let trs = document.querySelectorAll(".table tr");

        function showHiddenRows() {
        for (var i = 0; i < trs.length; i++) {
                trs[i].classList.remove("hidden");
            }
        }

        function setStyle() {
        if (tableData[key].status === "Approved") {
                    styling = "bg-success";
                    } else if (tableData[key].status === "Denied") {
                    styling = "bg-danger";
                }   
            for (var i = 0; i < tds.length; i++) {
                        if (tds[i].innerText === "Approved") {
                  tds[i].parentNode.setAttribute('class', 'bg-success')
                    } else if (tds[i].innerText === "Denied") {
                                    tds[i].parentNode.setAttribute('class', 'bg-danger')
                    }
            }
        }

        function filterTable(fa, fb) {
        for (var i = 0; i < tds.length; i++) {
                        if (tds[i].innerText === fa) {
                  tds[i].parentNode.setAttribute('class', 'hidden')
                    } else if (tds[i].innerText === fb) {
                                    tds[i].parentNode.setAttribute('class', 'hidden')
                    }
           }
        }



        if (selectValue === "all") {
                    showHiddenRows();
            setStyle(); 
        } else if (selectValue === "approved") {
             showHiddenRows();
           setStyle();      
           filterTable("Pending", "Denied");
            } else if (selectValue === "pending") {
            showHiddenRows();
            setStyle(); 
            filterTable("Approved", "Denied");
            } else if (selectValue === "denied") {
          showHiddenRows();
          setStyle();
          filterTable("Approved", "Pending");
        }

      {console.log(tableData[key].id)} 
        return <tr key={tableData[key].id} id={tableData[key].id} className={styling}>
        <td>{tableData[key].title}</td>
        <td>{tableData[key].status}</td>
        <td>{tableData[key].created_at.slice(0, 10)}</td>
        <td>{tableData[key].updated_at.slice(0, 10)}</td>
        <td><a href="#" onClick={() => { that.removeRow() }}>Delete</a></td>
        </tr>;

        })}
              </table>
            </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```